# fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode and if I run:
`g++ main.cpp`

I get this error:

> PS C:\Users\giorg\Documents\Development\Tests\node-addons-test\src> g++ main.cpp

```
main.cpp:2:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
                              ^
```

#### project/src/main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
  if ( argc != 2 )
  {
      printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
      return -1;
  }

  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if ( !image.data )
  {
      printf("No image data \n");
      return -1;
  }
  namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("Display Image", image);

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

#### project/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                "C:\\openCV\\opencv\\build\\include"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:\\openCV\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib"
                ]
            },
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17134.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

What should I do to start work with opencv on vscode?
Thanks in advance, I am sure there are more developers that have faced this problem and more of them is gonna face this on the feature.

### What I have tried

[image] it and is not working

#### Also, this files must be included but I don't know how

[image]

Comment: I know nothing about VScode but that `g++` looks more like `GCC` to me. Anyway, you need to tell the compiler where the OpenCV header files are with `-I /path/to/headers` and tell the linker where the OpenCV libraries are with `-L /path/to/libraries` and then say which libraries you want with `-lopencv -lhighgui ...`

Comment: I use minGW i am not if this what you mean, i am new to c++ world I have tried this but I get the same error, is this correct? 
`g++ main.cpp -I C/openCV/opencv/build/includes -L C/openCV.opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib`

Comment: I get the same error as before when i try this

Comment: this video shows how to use opencv with vs2107 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-VHaLHC4XI
can i do the same with vscode ?

Comment: try -I C:/andSoOn since you are in windows. Or are you using msys or another special bash console?

Comment: If you can see a bunch of files ending in`*.h` when you run `ls C/openCV/opencv/build/includes` then that is probably the correct thing to put after `-I`. Likewise if you see a bunch of library files if you type `ls C/opencv.opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib` then that is probably the correct thing to put after `-L`.

Comment: Mark thank you for that please look the new updates on the code I gonna post to see what I have tryit so far

Comment: I have tryit this command `g++ main.cpp -I "C:/openCV/opencv/sources/include" -L "C:/openCV/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib"` 
And this command
g++ main.cpp -I C:/openCV/opencv/sources/include -L C:/openCV/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib

Both of them not work

Comment: @MarkSetchell and I dont find any thing on the internet how to solve that problem, first time in my life , can you please try to install the opencv with vscode and try if this think realy works together is easy for you thanks

Comment: @GeorgeC. Could you find a solution? We are currently having the same issue. Thanks in advance