Error running opencv in C++ using visual studio
I am trying to run the code below:
// Importing libraries

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main() {
    // Load the image
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("input.jpg");
    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not load image." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert the image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayImage;
    cv::cvtColor(image, grayImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Save the grayscale image
    cv::imwrite("output_gray.jpg", grayImage);

    // Display the images
    cv::imshow("Original Image", image);
    cv::imshow("Grayscale Image", grayImage);
    
    // Wait for a key press indefinitely
    cv::waitKey(0);
    
    return 0;
}

While I've installed mingw64 as the compiler, and downloaded "opencv-4.10.0-windows" and extracted in my local folder. I need to mention that I have added the path for "mingw64\bin" , "opencv\build\x64\mingw64\bin" and "opencv\build\x64\mingw64\lib" to the environment variable path. But when I am running the above-mentioned code, it spit out an error:
"
Basic image processing.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

"
Any idea and comments?

PATH is only for executables, it doesn't do anything for headers and libraries. Use the -I flag to tell the compiler where to look for headers, then -L for where to look for .a files, and link the .a files using -l. Or stop using stone age technology: install MSYS2, use it to install MinGW, OpenCV and pkgconf, and use pkgconf to automatically determine the correct compiler flags for OpenCV.

Also Visual Studio != Visual Studio Code, pick one. It seems you're using the latter.

the code can not spit out an error. the compiler, or linker, maybe preprocessor, yes, they caan

@HolyBlackCat visual code is a recent technology. i use it on every day basis.

In VSCode under windows you should have followed the official MinGW instructions and install msys2 and use that to install your MinGW compiler using the msys2 package manager pacman. After that you should have used pacman to install opencv for the recommended ucrt64 environment using this command in a msys terminal: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-opencv after that you edit your tasks.json to link to the opencv libraries. You will not have to set an include directory or linker path since pacman installs to the system location of the compiler.

Visual Code ≠ Visual Studio Code ≠ Visual Studio.

Here are is the VSCode MinGW instructions so you understand the role of the 3 json files: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw and use the recommended msys2 MinGW

This question is similar to: Build OpenCV application with MSVS compiler in VSCode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

that's a generic "include file not found" error. that's not novel. plenty of existing questions, and existing answers, both specific to OpenCV, and not.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571894/fatal-error-opencv2-opencv-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory

@user14063792468 By stone age tech I mean manually downloading library binaries and then guessing flags, as opposed to package managers and pkgconf.
